# Is there any kafka version where the pollTimeout was 500ms?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'am facing a behaviour change after upgrade spring version from 2.3.12.RELEASE to 2.7.5 where We have a karate test that fails on purpose the delivery of a kafka message and the listener goes to the topic in each 500ms to try re-send the message and when I changed for this new version it uses the default pollTimeout of 5000ms, the only way I could reproduce the same behaviour was setting the pollTimeout on container factory configuration. I'am asking that because in the previous version there is not explicit place setting pollTimeout so I was wondering if could be something by default. But in the documentation it's seems that the default value was always 5000ms, that said any advice or ideas would be nice to read.

Comment: It has been 5 seconds (increased from 1) since (spring-kafka) 2.2.0.RELEASE 5 years ago.

Comment: Yeah ... I looked all over the documentation .. the think is that I did not find anywhere in our code where this property is being set and it makes me wonder if it could be something by default.

Comment: @GaryRussell this configuration is made through container factory in both versions ... there is no way to the KafkaListener try to consume the message again in less than 5000ms if the pollTimeout is not explicit set? Additionally when the message fails it has a nack of 15 ms

Comment: You need to show the test method and explain exactly what the behavior change is.